# Match and exclude multiple classes with Watir

Tags: ruby, watir

I would like to be able to match against a class while excluding certain classes as well.

I can use something like follows to get all li elements that match the specified class, but I'm not sure how I can screen out classes at the same time.

```
b = Watir::Browser.new
free_boxes = b.lis(:class, /cellGridGameStandard/)
```

I would like to change this into something that will match all li elements with the `cellGridGameStandard` class, but excludes all elements that also contain either the `notEligible` class or the `ownAlready` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of options.

Let us assume that the html is like:

```
<ul>
    <li class="cellGridGameStandard">
        Element 1
    </li>
    <li class="cellGridGameStandard ownAlready">
        Element 2
    </li>
    <li class="cellGridGameStandard notEligible">
        Element 3
    </li>
    <li class="cellGridGameStandard">
        Element 4
    </li>
</ul>
```

The first and fourth li elements match the specified criteria.

One option would be to check for lis that do not have the `ownAlready` or `notEligible` class:

```
matching = browser.lis(:class => 'cellGridGameStandard')
    .find_all { |li|
        ['ownAlready', 'notEligible'].none? { 
            |class_name| li.class_name.split.include? class_name
        }
    }
p matching.collect(&:text)
#=> ["Element 1", "Element 4"]
```

Another option, which is easier to write but sometimes considered harder to read, is to use a css locator:

```
matching = browser.elements(:css => 'li.cellGridGameStandard:not(.ownAlready):not(.notEligible)')
p matching.collect(&:text)
#=> ["Element 1", "Element 4"]
```

Comment: Thanks; just what I needed. I went with the css locator option. Nice and concise.